# Text classification based on interests or topics for short texts

Tags: nlp

This question (CC BY-SA) was posted on https://stackoverflow.com/q/28181599/395857 by [PS1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210450/ps1) but was deleted, so I'm reposting it here.

> I have been searching for sparse text classification tool, that can classify based on dmoz or freebase for sparse/short texts - like tweets.  I have looked at general classification tools like sci-kit. What other most common tools do data scientists use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LibShortText](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libshorttext/):

- gratis and open source (Python + C)
- works on UNIX systems

> LibShortText is an open source library for short-text classification and analysis. Properties of short texts are considered in its design and implementation. The package supports effective text pre-processing and fast training/prediction procedures. We provide an interactive tool to perform error analysis. Because of the short length, details of each short text can
> be investigated easily. In addition, the package is designed so that users can conveniently make extensions. The ease of use, efficiency, and extensibility of LibShortText make it very useful for practitioners working on short-text classification and analysis. The package is
> available at [http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libshorttext)